# Looping through a list of directories to make subdirectories

Tags: python, loops, terminal, directory

I have a directory full of subdirectories.

What I would like to do is write a Python script that loops through each of those
sub-directories and for each one it creates an additional subdirectory and populates
it with three files.

For example:

```
directories = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

for fruit in directories:

# 1) create subdirectory called "files"
# 2) Populate "files" with file1, file2, file3
```

I am familiar with creating directories and files on Terminal's command line (Mac)
but I don't know how to call those commands from Python.

I would greatly appreciate advice on what those commands look like and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the builtin functions **os.path.walk** (to walk through the directory tree) and **os.mkdir** (to actually create the directories).

Comment: I have been reading through the OS library trying to see where it talks about creating files in a similar fashion to creating a directory using mkdir, but I cant find anything. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Are you trying to create a new empty file and write to it or just copy one from somewhere else? If you want to write to a new file, use the builtin [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function and write to the file. If you want to copy an existing file, use [shutil.copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

Answer (score 0):

Python [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module has all you need for creating the directories, particularly [`os.mkdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir).

You don't say what you want in that files. If you want a copy of another ("template") file, use [shutil.copy()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)  If you want to create a new file and wrrite from that from your script, a built-in [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) will suffice.

Here's an example (note that it assumes that the "fruit" directories already exist in current directory *and* that subdirectory "files" does not exist yet):

```
import os
import shutil

directories = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

for fruit in directories:

    os.mkdir("%s/files" % fruit)

    with open("%s/files/like" % fruit, "w") as fp:
        fp.write("I like %ss" % fruit)
    fp.close()

    with open("%s/files/hate" % fruit, "w") as fp:
        fp.write("I hate %ss" % fruit)
    fp.close()

    with open("%s/files/dont_care_about" % fruit, "w") as fp:
        fp.write("I don't care about %ss" % fruit)
    fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use python `import os` and  `os.system('command_to_run_in_shell')`
and you are ready to go!!